# XSLT nested TOC

Tags: xml, xslt

It should parse a table of content from an XML-File and output an HTML with an ordered List.
I tried something like below but its showing duplicate entries (first title twice) and an empty li tag and i can't figure out how to remove them.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<document>
    <section>
        <title>Section One</title>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>Section Two</title>
        <section>
            <title>Section Two.One</title>
        </section>
        <section>
            <title>Section Two.Two</title>
            <section>
                <title>Section Two.Two.One</title>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>Section Three</title>
    </section>
</document>


My XSLT:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="document">
        <html>

        <head>
        </head>

        <body>
            <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ol>
        </body>

        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <li>

            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            <xsl:if test="section">
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="title" />
                        <xsl:if test="section">
                            <li>

                                <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />
                            </li>
                        </xsl:if>

                    </li>
                </ol>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output:

[image: xslt output]

Could it be a grouping problem? I have sequential elements and i want to nested it without empty li tags. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/document">
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />
            </ol>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
        <xsl:if test="section">
            <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />
            </ol>
        </xsl:if>  
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```